# Find strings enclosed in quotes and equal-signs using RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to parse strings using JavaScript. The strings are either enclosed in quotes or are a single `=` character.

**Examples:**

```
"String 1" "String 2" "String 3"
"String 1" = "String 3"
"String 1" "String 2" =
"String 1" = =
```

I've discovered the following RegEx pattern that covers the first case only  – at least when I use it on [RegExr](https://regexr.com/), it does not work in JavaScript: `(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1`

**Example:**

```
const re = /(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1/;
const str = '"String 1" "String 2" "String 3"';

re.exec(str);

//=> [""String 1"", """, "", index: 0, input: ""String 1" "String 2" "String 3"", groups: undefined]
```

How can I translate this pattern to work in JavaScript and how can I add the `=` to the pattern?

Comment: Do you want to match even `=` symbols? Like https://regex101.com/r/uUaETJ/2? To get multiple matches use `exec` in a loop until no match found. Or use `s.match(/regex/g)`.

Comment: Take the second example, I'm expecting three results `"String 1"`, `=` and `"String 3"`

Comment: `s.match(/(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1|=/g)`? See https://regex101.com/r/uUaETJ/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're not concerned with escaped quotations marks (e.g. `"a\"b"`), then this regex will match quoted strings or equal signs: `"[^"]*"|'[^"]*'|=`. You could use it as:

```js
let input = `"String 1" "String 2" 'String 3' = = "string 4"`;

let matches = input.match(/"[^"]*"|'[^"]*'|=/g);
console.log(matches);

[
  "\"String 1\"",
  "\"String 2\"",
  "'String 3'",
  "=",
  "=",
  "\"string 4\""
]
```